# Is there a way to share a link to a public Google+ post?

Tags: google-plus, sharing, links

I know I can re-share the post to my stream, but how do I point a non Google+ user to a publicly shared post?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you might expect, there are multiple ways of doing this. There's [using the timestamp to get the permalink](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18650/is-there-a-way-to-share-a-link-to-a-public-google-post/18652#18652) (as detailed by [Eight Days of Malaise](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/410/eight-days-of-malaise)), then there's this:

The down-pointing arrow in the upper right of any post offers a menu (see below).

[image: Google Plus post menu]

"Link to this post" is the direct link to the post.

Answer (score 6):

At the top of the post there will be a timestamp between the name of the Google+ user and sharing range.

[image: where to find permalink]

Click on that and you'll get a page for that post alone.

That link is what you can share with other users not on Google+.